# Should I clean up my *old* lower-quality questions?

Tags: discussion

Clearly, we should all be asking high-quality questions to begin with.

Unfortunately however, I have some rather shameful questions in my past, and am sometimes particularly motivated to improve the quality of them in terms of formatting, etc. while leaving the question itself in tact.

I have been prompted to ask *this* question, as [one example of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578340/pointer-being-freed-was-not-allocated-it-was) hit the 'Popular Question' mark of 1000 views today, which I would think is a good reason to want to make it  a 'better question'.

That example could actually be a lot worse, but in particular I think the title is poor - and the body would probably benefit from at least one line break.

A frequent example of the sort of improvement I mean would be removing the 'story element' of some poor questions, that make them highly and unnecessarily specific.

---

Am I right to want to improve old and popular questions - or should they just be left to lie, particularly if they have good answers; so should not be 'bumped' for any real reason?

Comment: If the changes would be really minor then I  suggest not to. Editing pushes your post in the active questions queue.

Comment: @juergend That's really at the crux of my question - it's the improvement vs (unnecessarily) bumping up queue.

Comment: It will be visible in the active question list for around 5 minutes. Improved titles are really helpful for future visitors. Just do it.

Comment: There wouldn't be a badge for that if the devs of SO didn't want you to do it.

Comment: Yes, fix them - just don't do sequences of old questions quickly, so the front page is not inundated with old material.

Comment: +1, was just thinking of this same conundrum this morning. :)

Comment: @juergend: And what's wrong with that? If you don't want to see active questions, then don't view the "active questions" page. Simple! Try the "new questions" page instead.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

## YES!

Who cares about bumping? That question has attracted an average of 6 viewers a day in its short life so far *without* being bumped - chances are, it's showing up in searches. Is it useful to the folks finding it? Misleading them? Confusing them? If you think it might be, then fix it!

How many chances do you get to make an edit that'll benefit 6 people a day? **Just do it!**

Comment: I care about bumping!  Zombie questions are a menace (though perhaps not as much on SO as on SU).

Comment: @hotlicks Why are zombie questions a menace? They are questions, not current event topics. Questions don't have expiration dates. They don't stop being useful. Most of the useful questions I run across are years old whenever they get bumped to first page.

Comment: @zero298 I suppose on SU (as mentioned) a question might be Windows XP specific for example, which has passed its expiration date. That doesn't make it totally not useful, but certainly a lot less so.

Comment: @OllieFord People still use XP…

Comment: @OllieFord - just because something is old tech and not supported by the manufacturer doesn't mean the questions about it aren't useful. I've spent a lot of my career dealing with no-longer-supported equipment, software platforms, etc.

Comment: Of course, but it certainly decreases in relevance. I'm not saying it should be deleted - just that that may be why Hot Licks would rather not have the bump.

Comment: @HotLicks I run accross SO answers that address a question I have but for very old software versions which few (if any) people use today. They got lots of votes way back when, but now they're zombies. Often it's clear it's for old versions, but often enough not, and you waste time finding out by trial + further research. Of course, that's not the case with questions relating to this MSO question (:

Comment: @drevicko - Yeah, that's sort of what I'm talking about.  Someone edits an old question and five people see it and respond to it without checking the date, not really adding anything (especially on SU where many questions are very specific to a given user and situation that is long gone by the time these responses are posted).  It's a waste of time for the posters and a waste of virtual paper for SO.

Comment: @drevicko: in this case, you might consider enriching the questions by specifying the version of the software/hardware it concerns. It can be done either in the text of the question itself and/or as a tag for example. For better or worse, old questions are likely to be better referenced in search engines so it's worth clarifying the context... Another solution is to actually tag the ANSWER itself with the version, and posting a new answer for the new version; this way people finding the question get tailored answers for their own setup.

Answer (score 4):

I clean up also older questions I run over when I come there from some google result. It's just to leave a better place than I've found before. Bumping? I wish more old questions would appear on the homepage because they are normally of better quality - at least when I actually edit those.

If the old question was just crap, I vote to delete etc.. No need to polish crap, just to take the dirt out of the house.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you should, especially for the example you've given. I'm not entirely sure you should remove the 'story element', as this sometimes gives clues as to why you were seeking the answer in the first place, but in terms of improving layout, providing better detail etc etc then I would definitely go for it.

The only thing that does surprise me is that despite the high number of views, the question you referred to only has one upvote. I wonder if this means the question appears in searches, so people look at it, but is not very helpful to other people after all. Maybe improving your question would resolve this ....

Comment: It may appear in searches because of the generic error description. ... I wish I had seen this 6 months ago! It describes *exactly* a bug I had to fight, and only head-ache inducing one-line at a time debugging *finally* revealed this as the cause.

Answer (score -16):

The problem with "cleaning up" is that you're essentially disturbing an old conversation.  Say you "clean up" an old answer, and introduce an error in an answer with 10 upvotes.  The wrong version of the answer will still have 10 upvotes!  Even if you do not introduce an error, your updated answer is just not what the community voted for.

Even if you just "fix" a question, the tone of the question changes.  Initially people could see by the question that you were new to programming (or English, or the web.)  Now, you'll look like a more advanced programmer asking a newbie question.  The right response to that is very different.

Comment: I think that would be a reasonable concern were it not for the fact that the last editor is visible near the original questioner on the page.

Comment: `Now, you'll look like a more advanced programmer asking a newbie question. The right response to that is very different.` I couldn't disagree with this more. If you're casting votes on questions based on how talented you think the OP is or should be, then you're abusing your right to vote. You should _always_ be voting on the post's content.

Comment: To paraphrase @Lightness: if you pay any attention to the questioner at all, or try to account for or help them with their specific circumstances, then you're not doing what SO was originally intended to do and what is being increasingly encouraged: build an archive of useful information for future visitors in the form of Q&A. Assisting the OP *in any way whatsoever* should be a totally accidental consequence of that. At any rate, that's the extreme position, which different people hold to different degrees.