# Should I clean up this old question?

Tags: discussion, clean-up, self-answer

This is very strongly related to [Should I clean up my *old* lower-quality questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258762/should-i-clean-up-my-old-lower-quality-questions)

However, I think [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999413/how-to-force-control-content-redraw-within-event-handler) is more a grey area. It's two years old and has 462 views (as of this meta post, which may likely change that). It has no votes on the question or the answer, and the problem was a minor mistake.  However, I do see that searching for phrases such as "force control redraw from event handler" do show it to be top (for my region) result in search engines.

With people arriving to the question from Google, etc, I can't tell if the code I've put there is of any help to them.  Is this question worth keeping?  Or too specific?

Comment: 462 views in 2 years is less for a C# question. Can be deleted.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion be careful about recommending deletion to people, it can get them into post bans if they delete too many of their own posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that question and answer has some value. Instead of just referring to the comments section in your answer, you could make it better by quoting what the problem was.

> You need to move the logon verification into another thread, it's blocking the UI thread.

That will make it more clear what the code in your answer is doing. The differences between your original code and the solution are a little bit subtle, particularly to those of us who aren't familiar with C# threading.